# How initial delay counting in chaining works?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-workmanager

When `initialDelay` will start counting in this case: individual for each request or common?

```kotlin
val triggerRequests = triggers.map {
    OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TriggerWorker>()
        .setInitialDelay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()
}


var workContinuation = workManager.beginWith(triggerRequests[0])
triggerRequests.subList(1, triggerRequests.size).forEach() {
    workContinuation = workContinuation.then(it)
}
workContinuation.enqueue()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work for the first startup. will not be included in the next.